# is there a faster alternative to mwdumper to import xmls?

Tags: xml, mediawiki

I am looking for a faster alternative to using mwdumper for importing mediawiki xml dumps. 
I had used wget to download the xmls one by one for large articles and there are a few hundreds that I need to import. Importing one at a time is taking too long

the command 
    java -jar mwdumper.jar --format=sql:1.5 page1.xml | mysql -u username -d databasename
does not seem to be working on Windows command line.

Comment: There is no | (pipe) in Windows. `mwdumper` has an option to write the results directly into a database though.

Comment: thx @Tgr do you know what that option is? the way i have been doing it is open mwdumper.jar, browse for the file, connect to the database and import, then repeat that for each file.

Comment: `--output=mysql:<jdbc url>` where thwe [JDBC url](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) looks like `mysql://<host>/<database>?user=<username>&password=<password>`. You can find this along with all other options in [the documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MWDumper). (No guarantees it works, though; I seem to recall having problems with it, but that was a long time ago.)

Comment: I assume you read https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing ?

Answer (score 0):

I have compared several available options. `maintenance/importDump.php` has been a winner for me:

- It's part of MediaWiki itself, so more likely to remain supported and less chance of anomalies (which you will certainly get if you start messing with SQL queries yourself).
- It's at least twice as fast as some code I had based on code from `maintenance/edit.php`.
- It can run on an existing MediaWiki setup.
- It works well with [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).
- Nice feedback in the form of `20.23 revs/sec`